# Is null check of field annotated with javax.inject.Inject required

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, annotations, inject

I have a class where I have injected a field using `javax.inject.Inject` annotation

```
import javax.inject.Inject;

public class Foo extends BaseFoo {
  @Inject
  private Bar bar;
  ...

  public void execute(){
    if (bar == null) {
      //log failure message and return
      return;
    }
    //Do your work..
  }
  ...
}
```

My question is whether in the above example, is `null` check needed or not? and why?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'd use an injectable constructor to a final field.

Comment: Thanks for the accept. Let me know if there is anything I could do to make my answer upvote worth in your eyes, like adding other information...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: it depends.

If you *think* there are valid scenarios, where the injection process will not inject **null**, then you do need that check. If you think that should never happen, then you probably end up with a NPE at runtime; and then again; you have to figure for yourself if that behavior is "appropriate" in your context (and what/how to deal with it then).

But I would rather strive to make that field final and put the annotation on your constructor; and then you can just put a `Objects.requireNonNull()` check on the incoming argument; and you are later on sure that any Foo object of are **null free**.